# Overriding differently nested object values

Tags: typescript

Having an object like:

```
const myList = {
    object1: {
        type1: {
            val: 1
        }
    },
    object2: {
        type1: {
            val: 1
        }
    },
    object3: {
        type2: {
            val: 1
        }
    },
}
```

How would I override all `val` values nested in a `type1`?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should work.

```js
for (const key in myList) {
  if ('type1' in myList[key]) {
    myList[key].type1.val = 'foo'
  }
}
```

The above example overrides all `val` in nested `type1` to `"foo"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to modify `val` in `type1`, so I am assuming there is a fixed path you want to access in your nested objects.
The easiest way is to loop through your `objectN` and use an hardcoded path:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(myList)) {
  myList[key].type1.val = newVal;
}
```

---

If you want a more dynamic solution to use to explore different paths in your nested object you could use `array.prototype.reduce` in a similar way:

```
function fromPathToObj(path, object) {
  // path = "type1.val"
  // path is splitted in valid keys, and they are used to access the values with reduce
  return path.split(".").reduce((acc, key) => acc[key],object);
}
```

The previous snippet would become

```
for (const key of Object.keys(myList)) {
  fromPathToObj("type1.val", myList[key]) = newVal;
}
```

Note: I'm not sure this second solution will modify the original object or you create deep copies of `objectN` with `fromPathToObj`, but I think it's worth trying.